# Populating picture boxes from file path. Windows Metro App, Store App, Windows 8 App

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Pretty much I must find a way to populate image boxes with the corresponding information to the images, if it's possible in a Windows 8/Metro/Store App. I have a database with all the physical paths of the images which are stored on the local computer e.g: "c:\BookImages\spud.jpg". Now when i pull the information from the database with information about the book, I also take the file path of image("c:\BookImages\spud.jpg"). All i need to now do is to fetch the image and display it in a image box. But i do not how to do this, i have been researching for a while now, and I'm coming to the understanding that i cannot select file's from other than the actual install directory of the windows app. Unless i use a FileOpenPicker, which will be a useless for the user to select the folder which contains the images every time they run the app. If anyone has a solution to my problem please let me know it will be much appreciated.

Comment: Save the StorageFolder in the Windows.Storage.AccessCache--see my fuller reply below.

Answer (score 0):

See If all the directories were given access for a win rt app then it would be a security risk 
So some specific folder are available try storing user data in there . After that only File Picker can Help.

Heres the link

[Folders for winrt](http://lunarfrog.com/blog/2012/05/21/winrt-folders-access/)

Its a Microsoft policy so Please design app accordingly. You might needd to set capabilities in the app manifest file for some folders. Please go through it :)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to have the user pick the folder once and save the StorageFolder in the Windows.Storage.AccessCache.

The long answer is that all this boils down to having your data store in a place that is programmatically accessible.

One option, as Anobik pointed out, is to use either your appdata folders (where you have open access), or something like the Pictures Library, which you can access given a capability in the manifest. This way you don't need to ask the user.

If you use the file picker to let the user select a folder for the data store, he or she has granted permission to access that folder programmatically, including its contained files. 
**The important thing** is that you have to preserve that permission across sessions, which is the purpose of the AccessCache.

Think of a StorageFolder object (and a StorageFile) as an abstraction for a pathname--you never really want to save pathname strings unless you have inherent programmatic access to that location. This isn't true for stuff from the file picker, so you have to use the AccessCache to essentially save the folder reference and its permissions.

Kraig Brockschmidt
Author, [Programming Windows 8 Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2012/10/29/free-ebook-programming-windows-8-apps-with-html-css-and-javascript.aspx), a free ebook from Microsoft Press (also see [second edition preview](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2))